# php domelement - run method on insert?

Tags: php, domdocument

Well, what I more or less look for is an eventhandler in php... - I think.

I'm writing a php script to make an xml-file (ansi n42.42 file to be exact) What I want to do is to be able to define various "sub-trees" and merge those together into the final DOMDocument. I am defining each of those subtrees as extended DOMNode with those attributes I need for building the subtree. As the domnode is immutable until it is inserted into a DOMDocument, I am defining a build method that I run after I've interted it to set up things:

Eg in my class: (some parts removed for brevity)

```
class calibration extends DOMElement{
  var $calibtype="Energy";
  var $coefficients;
  var $id;

  function calibration($coeff,$id=false){
    parent::__construct('Calibration');
    $this->coefficients=$coeff;
    $this->id=$id;
  }
  function build(){ // must be called after the calibration is inserted into a dom-tree.
    $this->setAttribute('Type',$this->calibtype);
    $DOM=$this->ownerDocument;
    $node=$DOM->createElement('Equation');
  }
```

And then to use it:

```
$cal = new calibration("-4, 3.12","cal_id");
$n42->firstChild->appendChild($cal);  // n42 is the object extending DOMDocument
$cal->build();
```

Is it somehow possible to make $cal->build() run automatically when $cal is appended into the tree?

(Or am I maybe barking up the wrong tree, would I be better off using DOMFragment from the start?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you right, then you could just add observers to your script and they will take responsibility for changing DOMDocument. That is if I understood you correctly.

Comment: Observes - sounds like what I need! Thansk @Eugene!